# SQL Oracle - Union same ID column from 100s of tables to find max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a select query to find the highest value from an ID column where the sequence is 'shared' across the entire database of hundreds of tables. (Note the sequence does not exist as a formal Sequence within SQL Developer)

The database (which I didn't create/own), creates a unique ID for each record in any table which is sequential, appended with a suffix.

i.e.
psi.Customer

```
OID
1001AAA
1002AAA
1003AAA
1006AAA
```

psi.Item

```
OID
1004BBB
1005BBB
1007BBB
```

- so you can see the numerical sequence is used across all tables.

I would like to find the maximum value for the numerical sequence (ignore the suffix) for the entire database.

i.e.
**1007**

I'm satisfied I can create a union query over a few tables, to find the top answer:

```
select to_number(substr(oid,1,length(oid)-3)) from psi.Customer

union

select to_number(substr(oid,1,length(oid)-3)) from psi.Item

union

select to_number(substr(oid,1,length(oid)-3)) from psi.Country
order by 1 desc)
where rownum=1
```

but I don't want to add each named table. Instead, I want to create the union across any table which has a column name OID, and owned by schema 'PSI'

Comment: You can create the SQL statement for each table easily using lots of methods (dynamic sql, paste the table names into Excel and construct the command using CONCAT, etc) - but there’s no way round having to individually query each table

Comment: You can certainly script this easily enough with PL/SQL, but if the application that loads these tables knows what the next value to use is, then it has to have a sequence or something it's using, and you should be able to just find that and get your number. I doubt the app is itself querying all the tables to get max value and then incremented every time it needs to create a new row. By the way, even with a sequence, this is a horrible design idea.

Comment: @PaulW, agreed the sequence must exist elsewhere, but it's not a Sequence in the schema. And agreed re the design! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If all your data has the leading zeroes and is the same length, then you do not need to take the sub-string of the leading digits (as a numeric sort and an alpha-numeric sort would be identical):

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id  VARCHAR2(20);
  v_tn  VARCHAR2(30);
  v_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT owner, table_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  column_name = 'ID'
    AND    owner = 'PSI'
    AND    REGEXP_LIKE(table_name, '^TABLE\d+$')
  )
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := EMPTY_CLOB();
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    v_sql := v_sql || 'SELECT MAX(id) id, ''' || r.table_name || ''' tn FROM ' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name;
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY';

  -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_id, v_tn;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_tn || ': ' || v_id );
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1(id) AS
SELECT '00001AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00002BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00003CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00014DDD' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2(id) AS
SELECT '00005AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00006BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00027CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00009DDD' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3(id) AS
SELECT '00165AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00010BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00040CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00060DDD' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TABLE3: 00165AAA
> ```

If you have differing length strings then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id  VARCHAR2(20);
  v_tn  VARCHAR2(30);
  v_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT owner, table_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  column_name = 'ID'
    AND    owner = 'PSI'
    AND    REGEXP_LIKE(table_name, '^TABLE\d+$')
  )
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := EMPTY_CLOB();
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    v_sql := v_sql || 'SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(id, 1, LENGTH(id) - 3))) id, ''' || r.table_name || ''' tn FROM ' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name;
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY';

  -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_id, v_tn;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_tn || ': ' || v_id );
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> TABLE3: 165
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4k0MrgQF)

Comment: Apologies, the 000 padding was misleading, there are indeed different string lengths

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to create a view based on tables that contain `OID` column; then select value you're interested in.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table table1 (oid, name) as
  2    select '0001AAA', 'Little' from dual union all
  3    select '0002AAA', 'Foot'   from dual union all
  4    select '0003AAA', 'Scott'  from dual union all
  5    select '0006AAA', 'Tiger'  from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (oid, address) as
  2    select '0004BBB', 'London' from dual union all
  3    select '0005BBB', 'Paris'  from dual union all
  4    select '0007BBB', 'Rome'   from dual;

Table created.
```

Code that creates a view:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(4000);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select t.table_name
  5                  from user_tab_columns c join user_tables t on
  6                    t.table_name = c.table_name
  7                  where c.column_name = 'OID'
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      l_str := l_str || 'select oid from ' || cur_r.table_name || ' union all ';
 11    end loop;
 12    l_str := rtrim(l_str, ' union all');
 13    execute immediate 'create or replace view v_oid as ' || l_str;
 14  end;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

View contents:

```
SQL> select * From v_oid;

OID
-------
0001AAA
0002AAA
0003AAA
0006AAA
0004BBB
0005BBB
0007BBB

7 rows selected.
```

Max *sequence* value:

```
SQL> select max(regexp_substr(oid, '\d+')) result from v_oid;

RESULT
----------------------------
0007

SQL>
```

(that's just a simple way to fetch that value; use substr + instr combination, if you want - it'll perform better on large data set, but you know how to do that anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to generating a `union`, you could use an XML trick:

```
with cte (table_name, xml) as (
  select table_name,
    dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select max(id) as id from "' || table_name || '"')
  from all_tab_columns
  where column_name = 'OID' -- you said you wanted this, not sure if you meant ID?
  and owner = 'PSI'
)
select max(cte.table_name) keep (dense_rank last order by x.id) as table_name,
  max(x.id) as id
from cte
cross apply xmltable(
  '/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing cte.xml
  columns id varchar2(8) path 'ID'
) x;
```

That's still using dynamic SQL internally, but without having to manually build it up, or use PL/SQL.

'Borrowing' @MT0's data that gets the same result:

| TABLE_NAME | ID |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE3 | 00165AAA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VdTNXuF_) with some variations and intermediate steps to show what's happening. You can adapt it to only return the padded numeric part if you need to.

Comment: You may also add filtering on "table_name" to avoid scanning VIEWs, TABLEs behind MATERIALIZED VIEWs and MLOG$_% ones... and restrict the column to be of the exact type you are looking for to avoid possible errors due to implicit type conversion failures in case you have columns with same name but different types in some tables...

Answer (score 0):

You can use oracle cols table to achieve your requirement.

```
select
case when row_number = max(row_number) over() then replace(query, 'union all', '')
else query end as query
from
(select distinct 'select ' || to_number(substr(oid,1,length(oid)-3)) || ' from ' || table_name || ' union all ' as query, rownum as row_number,  column_name, table_name 
from cols where upper(column_name) in ('ODI'))
order by row_number;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting an error ORA-00904: "OID": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 61 which is 'oid' in the length(oid)... Also, is cols same as all_tab_columns? The queried tables should only be those owned by the schema 'PSI' (I failed to mention previously, sorry) - so I'm not sure in the query where that needs to be included.

Comment: You have to mention the right column name in the query and also the respective schema